# Edit and Continue does not work on Xamarin

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have my sample application `XamApp`. When I want to test Edit and continue on `XamApp.UWP` I'm getting this error:

```
Failed to emit module 'XamApp'
```

I've searched about this and I've done these so far:

- Disable IntelliTrace
- Enable "Suppress JIT optimization on module load (Managed only)"
- Unload `XamApp.Android` and `XamApp.iOS`
- Cleaning the solution.

Bus I'm still getting the error.

This is my config:

- Windows: 10.0.17763.1
- Visual Studio: 15.9.4
- Xamarin.Forms: 3.4.0.1008975
- .Net Standard: 2.0.3

Comment: Have you checked this issue? https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1574

Answer (score 0):

Add below codepiece to into your csproj file

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>Full</DebugType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

for sample usage see [Xamarin.Forms.Core](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Xamarin.Forms.Core.csproj#L6) repository.